# One colorbar for seaborn heatmaps in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

Here is an example that shows a colorbar for each subplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10,)))

fig,axn = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax in axn.flat:
    sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax)
```

[image]

How can I remove the colorbars for each subplot? I'd like to have only one colorbar that is either vertically or horizontally oriented. I know I have access to each colorbar axes via `fig.get_axes()[:-4]`, but how can I remove it from them entirely from the plot? I don't think there is an option to opt out of drawing the colorbar when heatmap is called.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `cbar` parameter controls whether a colorbar should be added, and the `cbar_ax` parameter can optionally specify the axes where the colorbar should go. So, you could do:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10,)))

fig, axn = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([.91, .3, .03, .4])

for i, ax in enumerate(axn.flat):
    sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax,
                cbar=i == 0,
                vmin=0, vmax=1,
                cbar_ax=None if i else cbar_ax)

fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, .9, 1])
```

(You'll get a warning about `tight_layout` here, but it actually is correct because we placed `cbar_ax` explicitly. If you don't like seeing the warning, you can also call `tight_layout` before plotting, but it won't be as tight).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this will also synchronize the colors? The way I see it it only will plot the colormap for the first axis, but the colormap will not necessarily be compatible to the other axes.

Comment: what does this part do `cbar=i == 0` ?
Assigning and then comparing to 0 ? why?

Comment: @Rotkiv, this is actually setting `cbar` as equal to `i == 0`, i.e. `cbar = True` if `i == 0`returns `True`.

Comment: How can I add x and y-axis label instead, 0,1,2---9.

Comment: @bayer, yes it syncronizes the colors, `vmin=0` and `vmax=1` takes care of that

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to synchronise the colours automatically, for when you don't know the limits a priori (and e.g. want to use the `robust` option)

Comment: This answer is so amazing! I came here to ask how to use tight_layout and this was already answered! Wish I can upvote again!

Answer (score 6):

It's actually not necessary to set `cbar_ax` to none for the first 3 subplots. You can set `cbar_ax=cbar_ax` for all 4 subplots and it will just paint the colorbar in the exact same spot 4 times, which dones't affect the look at all.

This works better for those using FacetGrid, e.g. given a dataframe `df`:

```
def draw_heatmap(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    d = data.pivot(index=args[1], columns=args[0], values=args[2])
    sns.heatmap(d, **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='col_name', col_wrap=2, margin_titles=True, sharey=True)

cbar_ax = g.fig.add_axes([.91, .15, .03, .7])
g = g.map_dataframe(draw_heatmap, 'col_col', 'index_col', 'val_col', annot=True, 
                    cmap='Spectral', cbar_ax=cbar_ax, cbar_kws={'label': 'color_bar_label'})
```