# One colorbar for multiple pandas subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to attach one colorbar for multiple pandas subplots.  Almost all the other questions that resolve the issue of putting one colorbar for multiple subplots use np arrays, not dataframes, to plot.

There is one question, [One colorbar for seaborn heatmaps in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356359/one-colorbar-for-seaborn-heatmaps-in-subplot), which seems like it could be useful, however I could not figure out how to extend it to my case.

Could anyone help?  Below is an example of my current code. Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# If you're using a notebook:
# %matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({"BASE": np.random.randn(10),
            "A": np.random.randn(10),
            "B": np.random.randn(10),
             "C": np.random.randn(10), 
             "D": np.random.randn(10),
            "color_col": [1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2]})




plt.figure(1, figsize = (15,15))

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = "A", c = df["color_col"], ax = plt.gca())

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = "B", c = df["color_col"], ax = plt.gca())

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = "C", c = df["color_col"], ax = plt.gca())

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = "D", c = df["color_col"], ax = plt.gca())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question [Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar) is probably more what you are looking for. **The problem is however that you do not directly have access to the mappable that is created in the pandas scatter plot.**

The solution here would be to distill this mappable (in this case a PatchCollection) from the axes using it `plt.gca().get_children()[0]`, which takes the first child artist from the axes.

This method is save as long as all scatterplots share the same colors and
 as long as there are no other artists in the axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"BASE": np.random.randn(10),
            "A": np.random.randn(10),
            "B": np.random.randn(10),
             "C": np.random.randn(10), 
             "D": np.random.randn(10),
            "color_col": np.random.randn(10)})

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (6,6))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, right=0.8, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
for i, col in enumerate("ABCD"):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
    df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = col, ax = plt.gca(), 
                    c = df["color_col"], cmap="jet", colorbar=False)

# we now take the first axes and 
# create a colorbar for it's first child (the PathCollection from scatter)
# this is save as long as all scatterplots share the same colors and
# as long as there are no other artists in the axes.
im = plt.gca().get_children()[0]
cax = fig.add_axes([0.85,0.1,0.03,0.8]) 
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here're a few stones at the target. I'm pretty sure at least one more method exists (using GridSpec differently than outlined below) but I like the latter two.

**1.** You could simply choose when to plot a color bar vs not, as long as you don't care if one of your subplots is trimmed to make room for the colorbar.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"BASE": np.random.randn(10),
            "A": np.random.randn(10),
            "B": np.random.randn(10),
             "C": np.random.randn(10), 
             "D": np.random.randn(10),
            "color_col": np.random.randn(10)})

fig,axis = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=4,figsize=(18,6)) 

for i, col in enumerate("ABCD"):
    ax = axis[i]
    df.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x = "BASE", y = col, c = df["color_col"], s = 55, cmap="jet", colorbar=(i==len("ABCD")-1))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**2.** If you really wanted 2X2 grid, and allsubplots must be same size, you could try this. I like the first answer, sans having to place color bar at a specific location. I'd rather draw everything I want, use existing tight_layout() functionality and then add a colorbar. The only magic number I retained is figsize.

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize = (9,4))

df = pd.DataFrame({"BASE": np.random.randn(10),
            "A": np.random.randn(10),
            "B": np.random.randn(10),
             "C": np.random.randn(10), 
             "D": np.random.randn(10),
            "color_col": np.random.randn(10)})

for i, col in enumerate("ABCD"):
    ax = axes[i/2][i%2]
    im = df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = col, ax = ax, s = 35,
                c = df["color_col"], cmap="jet", colorbar=False)
fig.tight_layout()
# Note: since colorbar is manu`enter code here`ally added, tight_layout must be called before
# rendering colorbar
plt.colorbar(plt.gca().get_children()[0], ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
```

[image]

**3.** Yet another approach would be to use gridspec as an argument to suplots constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

df = pd.DataFrame({"BASE": np.random.randn(10),
            "A": np.random.randn(10),
            "B": np.random.randn(10),
             "C": np.random.randn(10), 
             "D": np.random.randn(10),
            "color_col": np.random.randn(10)})

nrows,ncols = 2,2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, sharex='col', sharey=False,
                               gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 1,0.1]},
                               figsize=(7, 4))

for i, col in enumerate("ABCD"):
    ax = axes[i/(ncols)][i%(ncols)]
    im = df.plot.scatter(x = "BASE", y = col, ax = ax, s = 35
                         ,c = df["color_col"], cmap="jet", colorbar=False)

fig.tight_layout()
cax,kw = mpl.colorbar.make_axes([ax for ax in axes.flat])
plt.colorbar(axes[0][0].get_children()[0], cax=cax, **kw)

plt.show()
```

[image]