# Create a 2x2 grid of python seaborn heatmaps with shared axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am looking to create a 2 x 2 grid of seaborn heatmaps from a pandas dataframe in python, but I am having trouble getting the desired result. Currently, this code...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.uniform(0, 100, 1000), 
                   'y': np.random.uniform(0, 100, 1000), 
                   'z1': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000),
                   'z2': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000),
                   'z3': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000),
                   'z4': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)})

fig,axn = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
result0 = df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z1')
result1 = df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z2')
result2 = df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z3')
result3 = df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z4')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
sns.heatmap(result0, annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
sns.heatmap(result1, annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
sns.heatmap(result2, annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r')        
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
sns.heatmap(result3, annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r')
```

generates a graph that looks like this...
[image]

But the features I want to add are:

- Invert each of the y-axes, so that 0 is at the bottom and 100 at the top
- The grid should share both x and y axes, so that the ticks are not displayed unnecessarily
- The y-axis and x-axis ticks should be whole numbers, not decimals (despite the y series being floats
- Each grid should have a separate title
- The colour bar should be shared across all charts

That sample data doesn't really do the heatmap justice, but I couldn't figure out a better way atm. Any help solving five points above would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data that you have here, [`hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hexbin.html) makes more sense that `heatmap`. This solution uses [`ImageGrid`](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) to handle most of the requirements quite naturally. Note that I'm passing specific values for max and min so that the colorbar works correctly.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(2, 2), axes_pad=0.3, cbar_mode='single')

for ax, col in zip(grid, ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4']):
    hb = ax.hexbin(df.x, df.y, C=df[col], cmap='RdBu_r', vmin=0, vmax=1)
    ax.set_title(col)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')

grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(hb)
```

[image: sample hexbin]

Answer (score 3):

You can play with `xticklabels`, `yticklabels`, `cbar` parameters.

```
fig,axn = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 6))
xticks = ['{0:.0%}'.format(i/1000) if i % 100 == 0 else '' for i in range(1000)]
yticks = ['{0:.0%}'.format(i/1000) if i % 100 == 0 else '' for i in range(999, 0, -1)]
ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([.91, .3, .03, .4])

sns.heatmap(
    result0.iloc[-1::-1, -1::-1], annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r',
    xticklabels=False, yticklabels=yticks, cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Title 1')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
sns.heatmap(
    result1.iloc[-1::-1, -1::-1], annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r',
    xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Title 2')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
sns.heatmap(
    result2.iloc[-1::-1, -1::-1], annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r',
    xticklabels=xticks, yticklabels=yticks, cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Title 3')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
sns.heatmap(
    result3.iloc[-1::-1, -1::-1], annot=False, cmap='RdBu_r',
    xticklabels=xticks, yticklabels=False, cbar=True, cbar_ax=cbar_ax, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Title 4')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, .9, 1])
```

**References**

[One colorbar for seaborn heatmaps in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356359/one-colorbar-for-seaborn-heatmaps-in-subplot)

[How can I set the aspect ratio in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib)

[image]