# How to create a single colorbar for subplots when using seaborn kdeplot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am ploting by below code

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2 ,ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex='col', sharey='row')
sns.set_style("white")
a=sns.kdeplot(hour_listm[1], dfm[1].K,ax=ax1, cmap="PuBuGn",shade=True,cbar=False, shade_lowest=False)
b=sns.kdeplot(hour_listm[2], dfm[2].K,ax=ax2, cmap="PuBuGn",shade=True,cbar=False, shade_lowest=False)
c=sns.kdeplot(hour_listm[3], dfm[3].K,ax=ax3, cmap="PuBuGn",shade=True,cbar=False, shade_lowest=False)
d=sns.kdeplot(hour_listm[4], dfm[4].K,ax=ax4, cmap="PuBuGn",shade=True,cbar=False, shade_lowest=False)
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.set_ylim(0,0.5)
    ax.set_xlim(0,23)
    ax.label_outer()
```

Now if do cbar=True. I will get colorbar for each subplot. But I want only one colorbar for all the plot at a particular position. So how to do that? Any suggestions please.

Comment: Not kdeplots but the strategy should be the same:  [One colorbar for seaborn heatmaps in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356359/one-colorbar-for-seaborn-heatmaps-in-subplot)

Comment: But in this case, they use the same data for every subplot. In my case, dataset will change in every subplot.

Comment: Valid point. You can set the limits of the colorbar afterward but I have no time at the moment to look for a duplicate.

Comment: No. I want to mean that I have to vary the dataset. They use only one dataset. Like hour_listm[1], dfm[1].K    hour_listm[2], dfm[2].K but they use only df